# How to sum count in last 2 hours specific for each event in real time?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We're using Flink to monitor each event. The detail scenario is when a event arrives, flink find out all event with same userid in last 2 hours and sum the count field. For example:

```
    event1<userid1, n1, t0>     -> real time result = n1
    event2<userid2, n2, t0+1h>  -> real time result = n2
    event3<userid1, n3, t0+1h>  -> real time result = n1+n3
    event4<userid1, n4, t0+2.5h>  -> real time result = n3+n4
```

How could we implement such scenario in flink? Intuitively, we want to use sliding window, but there are two problems:

1. In flink, sliding window slides by parameter slide_size.
   However, in our scenario, window slides for each event, which
   means the start/end point of window is different for each
   event (expected window range: [eventtime-2h, eventtime)). Should we implement this by setting a small slide_size(10ms?)?
2. The process function is executed by trigger function, which means we can't get result immediately as soon as event arrive?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using the sliding window, but using your own `Trigger` to emit the elements arriving in the window. Sample code may like:

```
src.map(x => new Tuple2(x.id, x.value))
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(2), Time.seconds(1))
    .trigger(new Trigger[Tuple2[String, Int], TimeWindow] {
      override def onEventTime(time: Long, window: TimeWindow, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
        TriggerResult.CONTINUE
      }

      override def onProcessingTime(time: Long, window: TimeWindow, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
        TriggerResult.FIRE
      }

      override def clear(window: TimeWindow, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): Unit = {
      }

      override def onElement(element: Tuple2[String, Int], timestamp: Long, window: TimeWindow, ctx: Trigger.TriggerContext): TriggerResult = {
        TriggerResult.FIRE
      }
    })
  .sum(1)
```

Comment: David, when onElement method is called, is it possible that the window size is less than 3 sec in your sample code? For example, if current window is [t0, t0+3), and a event arrives at t0+1, then which window is onElement method processed on? [t0, t0+1)? In my use case, I want it to be [t0-1, t0+1)

Comment: I think in your case, the window size is 2 hours, sliding each hour. Assuming window size is 2 and sliding 1 and every event arrives on time(no late), then for the event at t0+1, it will be assigned to windows including [t0, t0+1], [t0+1, t0+2]

Comment: Is it a typo in your comment? If window size is 2, then the assigned windows should be [t0-1, t0+1], [t0, t0+2], [t0+1, t0+3]?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. You are right. They are: [t0-1, t0+1], [t0, t0+2], [t0+1, t0+3] ;)

Comment: Is there a way to slide window per event? for example, if event A arrives at t0, then the window is [t0-2, t0]; while another event B arrives at t1, then the window is [t1-2, t1].

Comment: Yeah, you can achieve this by using `KeyedStream.window(WindowAssigner)`. Assign the elements to the window through `WindowAssigner.assignWindows()`. You could refer to the Flink's internal window assigner for sliding time window: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/assigners/SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.java

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using `ProcessFunction`. [Here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html) is the detail.